# Proof that $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$ is converges almost surely.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

Let $\{a_n\} $ be a positive number sequence and $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. If we have $$\sup\limits_{t>0} \left( t. \mathbb{P} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n >t \right\}  \right) <\infty,$$ then $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$ is converges almost surely. Can you explain for me?

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a reference to the paper, book or other study materials where you saw this used (or assigned as an exercise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume $a_n$ are random variables. Label the events A := "$\sum_n a_n$ converges" and $B_N$ := "$\sum_n a_n > N$". We know that $\mathbb{P}[B_N] \leq C / N$ for all $N \geq 1$ for some $C \geq 0$. Note that $B_{N+1} \subset B_N$. Now, $\mathbb{P}[A^c] = \mathbb{P}[\bigcap_{N \geq M} B_N] \leq \mathbb{P}[B_M] \leq C / M$ for any $M \geq 1$. Taking $M \to \infty$ shows $\mathbb{P}[A^c] = 0$. Therefore $\mathbb{P}[A] = 1$. In other words, "$\sum_n a_n$ converges" almost surely.

Comment: Did you take $M\to\infty$?

Comment: @LeeWoo: yes, see edit